# Pérdida total de poderes administrativos sobre una carpeta de windows 10

Tags: windows10

Estoy teniendo problemas para acceder a una carpeta ya que perdí el control sobre ella, no me permite acceder las configuraciones de seguridad y no me permite modificar nada. Creo que fue por la instalación del navegador tor project, el cual ya no encuentro con el fin de desinstalar. He buscado bastante en internet pero los problemas no se asemejan y las respuestas no funcionan en este caso.

[image: Sin permisos para ver el archivo.]
[image: Sin posibilidad de modificar la seguridad]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, abre cmd como administrador, busca la carpeta y pon esto ejemplo

`takeown /a /r /d S /f D:\nombrecarpeta`  =windows en español

en ingles:

takeown `/a /r /d` Y `/f D:\nombre carpeta`

reinicia y prueba.

Las letras mayúsculas y minúsculas serán tomadas en cuenta.

Comment: Me dice que error de sintaxis debido a que la letra Y no se puede usar en este caso

Comment: se espera un atributo para /d, eso dice

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco la respuesta?

Comment: Y para windows en ingles S para windows en español D: es la unidad de disco si la carpeta esta  C: pues cambia D: por C:

Comment: Ejemplo windows en español  takeown /a/r/d S/f C:\carpeta  ....................windows en ingles takeown /a/r d Y/f C:\carpeta solo es cambiar la letra que esta en mayus dependiendo de la version de windows que tenga si es espa o ingles y cambiar letra de unidad